# Antd select not working inside a full screen dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd

I am using both materialui and antd as the ui component library in my react app. I have been using material ui's full screen [dialog](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/) and tried to insert antd's [select](https://ant.design/components/select/) inside the dialog.

But looks like select list doesn't render correctly when placed inside material-ui's dialog component. I have tried to give antd select a very large zindex with absolute position but no luck.

Here's a the codesanbox link. You can the select work out the dialog but same select component doesn't render it's option list when placed inside the full screen dialog

https://codesandbox.io/s/1zvj51xmj

Answer (score 4):

If I add `dropdownStyle={{ zIndex: 2000 }}` to the select it seems to work.

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks! FYI, this issue happens with a drawer component as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add zIndex=20 to Dialog Component and zIndex=2000 to Select

```
 <Dialog
    open={openSetTagsDialog}
    onClose={SetTagsDialoghandleClose}
    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-setTags"
    maxWidth={"md"}
    style={{zIndex:20}}
  >
 <Select style={{zIndex:2000}}>{...options...}</Select>
<Dialog>
```